# "\\" in file path os.path.join

Tags: python

Write a pyhton program to save data in .txt file, when create the file path, it errors, there are "\" in the path, why

the program:

```
#storage data in .txt file
def data_save_txt(type,data,id,name):
    # get the date when storage data
    date_storage()
    #create the data storage directory
    txt_parent_directory = os.path.join("dataset","txt",type,glovar.date)

    directory_create(txt_parent_directory)
    #write data in .txt
    if type == "group_members":
        txt_file_prefix = "gm"
    elif type == "group_feed":
        txt_file_prefix = "gf"
    elif type == "public_figure_posts":
        txt_file_prefix = "pfp"
    elif "user_" in type:
        txt_parent_directory = os.path.join("dataset", "txt", "user", type, glovar.date)
        txt_file_prefix = type
    txt_file_directory = os.path.join(txt_parent_directory,txt_file_prefix+"_"+time_storage()+"_"+id+"_"+name+".txt")
    txt_file_object = open(txt_file_directory,"w",encoding="utf-8")

    #to show the line number of stored data
    line_number = 1
    if isinstance(data,str):
        txt_file_object.write(data)
    elif isinstance(data,list):
        group_info_data = ''
        for i in range(len(data)):
            for (k, v) in data[i].items():
                group_info_data = group_info_data + str(line_number) + ")   " + k + ':' + str(v) + ','
            group_info_data += '\n'
            line_number += 1
        txt_file_object.write(group_info_data)
    txt_file_object.close()
```

when it run, it errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/PyCharmProject/FaceBookCrawl/FBCrawl.py", line 255, in <module>
    user_info_download.user_info_storage(user_id,user_info_type,u_access_token)
  File "C:\Python\PyCharmProject\FaceBookCrawl\user_info_download.py", line 79, in user_info_storage
    data_storage.data_save_txt(type,user_info,user_id,user_name)
  File "C:\Python\PyCharmProject\FaceBookCrawl\data_storage.py", line 29, in data_save_txt
    txt_file_object = open(txt_file_directory,"w",encoding="utf-8")
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dataset\\txt\\user\\user_friends\\20170121\\user_friends_20170121-124531_110286969468305_Du Bin.txt'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It point that

```
if "user_" in type:
        txt_parent_directory = os.path.join("dataset", "txt", "user", type, glovar.date)
```

this sentence errors, there are "\" in the path ,but I use os.path.join,  why,  who can help me for this issue

Comment: double slash is the normal way of python to display representation of strings containing slashes. Your problem is more likely because your file doesn't exist / your current directory is not the one you think it is.

Comment: If you `print('dataset\\txt\\user\\user_friends\\20170121\\user_friends_20170121-124531_110286969468305_Du Bin.txt')` you get `dataset\txt\user\user_friends\20170121\user_friends_20170121-124531_110286969468305_Du Bin.txt` - notice, no double backslashes. What you saw was a representation of the string where the `\` escape char is itself escaped.

Answer (score 1):

By calling

```
txt_parent_directory = os.path.join("dataset", "txt", "user", type, glovar.date)
txt_file_directory = os.path.join(txt_parent_directory,txt_file_prefix+"_"+time_storage()+"_"+id+"_"+name+".txt")
```

you are building the filename string `'dataset\txt\user\user_friends\20170121\user_friends_20170121-124531_110286969468305_Du Bin.txt'` The double backslashes are just Python's way of showing certain special characters.

But it does not create the actual folder. Run something like

```
os.makedirs()
```

on the directory before trying to create the file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that according to the error, you try to create a file in a directory that doesn't exist.

That is, the problem is in the directory name, not the file name.